# How to find duration of an uploaded mp4 or f4v video?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, duration, directshow.net

I've tried using **directshowlib-2005** by installing **k-lite mega codec pack**. It **can't find the duration of an mp4 file or f4v file (avi, wmv and flv has no problem)**. I use **ImediaSeeking** interface of directshowlib-2005 to find duration. But **in case of mp4 and f4v the GetDuration method returns zero**.

I know it is a codec problem, but I do not know which codec is to be installed to get duration of mp4 as well as f4v files.

The code I am using is shown below:

```
static public bool GetVideoLength(string fileName, out long length)
    {
        DirectShowLib.FilterGraph graphFilter = new DirectShowLib.FilterGraph();
        DirectShowLib.IGraphBuilder graphBuilder;
        //DirectShowLib.IMediaPosition mediaPos=null;
        DirectShowLib.IMediaSeeking mediaPos;
        length = 4294967296;

        try
        {
            graphBuilder = (DirectShowLib.IGraphBuilder)graphFilter;
            graphBuilder.RenderFile(fileName, null);
            //mediaPos = (DirectShowLib.IMediaPosition)graphBuilder;
            mediaPos = (DirectShowLib.IMediaSeeking)graphBuilder;                
           // mediaPos.get_Duration(out length);
            mediaPos.GetDuration(out length);

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {               
            mediaPos = null;
            graphBuilder = null;
            graphFilter = null;               

        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me by telling me the exact codec which should be installed to find the duration as mentioned above?

Comment: This answer to a slightly different question I asked would probably work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936816/querying-an-audio-video-file-for-information/3938722#3938722

Comment: And MP4 files can contain a variety of codecs. Could be H.264 (quite likely), or could well be something else.

Comment: Hi, While searching to find why my code doesn't work for mp4, i found the following statement:                                     "It doesn't matter whether it's in a container or not, it 
only matters whether you have a parser/reader for it. There 
is no stock DirectShow parser to read raw H.264 files and no 
third-party one I can think of. Also, whether IMediaSeeking 
would work with such a raw file is implementation-dependent. 
Last, most H.264-related filters use MPEG2Video or 
VideoInfo2 and neither works with MediaDet, so you would 
have to build the graph yourself." can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en). There is a CLI for it as well so you can call it from your code and get this info. It pretty much handles all kinds of codecs and containers.