# is there a way to get video length in php?

Tags: php, video, flv

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Define "Video" - what format? Where is it located, on your server or remote? Can you use ffmpeg?

Comment: get duration of flv file. sorry i'm new here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this post (Querying an audio/video file for information)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936816/querying-an-audio-video-file-for-information/3938722#3938722) I explained in detail how to use ffmpeg to get the length of a video file. Using the PHP `shell_exec()` command you can pass the necessary functions to ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Try Ffmpeg PHP library: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/